# Adding WMS layer in QGIS standalone Python script

Tags: pyqgis, wms, qgis-2

How do I add a WMS layer on a map, in a standalone Python script with QGIS 2.4?

The methodology explained at the bottom of the official QGIS documentation page seems to be outdated and does not work: http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can see, the example in the documentation is working, but not with the NASA JPL service. It says that NASA has stopped providing WMS support. You just have to look for another WMS service and fill in the required parameters:

```
urlWithParams = 'url=http://kaart.maaamet.ee/wms/alus&format=image/png&layers=MA-ALUS&styles=&crs=EPSG:3301'
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'MA-ALUS', 'wms')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

Be cautious, as if you don't fill out one of these parameters, because your WMS doesn't have one, QGIS will crash. In my example, the `MA-ALUS` layer doesn't have a style attribute, but I had to include it as an empty parameter.

Result:

[image: Eesti_wms]

**UPDATE:**

It works with QGIS 2.6.0, yaay!

```
from qgis.core import *

urlWithParams = 'url=http://kaart.maaamet.ee/wms/alus&format=image/png&layers=MA-ALUS&styles=&crs=EPSG:3301'
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'MA-ALUS', 'wms')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

**UPDATE for QGIS 3:**

It works with QGIS 3.2, after accounting for a https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html -- yaay!

```
from qgis.core import *

urlWithParams = 'url=http://kaart.maaamet.ee/wms/alus&format=image/png&layers=MA-ALUS&styles=&crs=EPSG:3301'
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'MA-ALUS', 'wms')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

Comment: Thanks Gabor!
It works if I run it in the QGIS python console, but if I do the same on a stand alone script I get this error message: QThreadStorage: Thread 0x20a4d40 exited after QThreadStorage 5 destroyed.
Then, the output map displays all the layers I want, except the WMS.

Comment: This might be an issue with the Qt implementation in QGIS. I'll try to look at it later, but you might need an answer from someone, who is more familiar with Qt.

Comment: The Styles parameter is required for all WMS GetMap requests, unless you supply an SLD parameter. `styles&` is sufficient to get the default style for the layer.

Comment: Your URL with params seems to be missing core WMS parameters, like `service=WMS&`, `request=GetMap&`, `version=1.3.0&`, `width=[num]&`, `height=[num]`.  Are these added on the fly by QGIS?

Comment: Also your service endpoint should be separated from the params by a question mark not an ampersand like: `http://kaart.maaamet.ee/wms/alus?format=image/png&`, note too that the WMS specification tells us that the Ampersand follows the key/value pair so we should always expect an Ampersand at the end of a list of params.