# Loading GeoServer WMS raster layer in QGIS Python console

Tags: qgis, geoserver, pyqgis, wms

I am using the following snippet to load a raster layer deployed under wms service using geoserver, in qgis python console. I am getting `False` output. Any idea?

```
registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()    
urlWithParams = "service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=sf:sfdem&styles=&bbox=589980.0,4913700.0,609000.0,4928010.0&width=512&height=385&srs=EPSG:26713&format=image/png&url=http://maps.itu.edu.tr:8082/geoserver/sf/wms?"
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer (urlWithParams , "my_title", "wms")
rlayer.isValid()
```

I have tried [this](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html), [How to load a WMS layer using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120823/how-to-load-a-wms-layer-using-pyqgis), and good enough web hunt but can't understand the issue. Is there any way to generate error code or info while working on qgis console?

Comment: what if the url is http://maps.itu.edu.tr:8082/geoserver/sf/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=sf:sfdem&styles=&bbox=589980.0,4913700.0,609000.0,4928010.0&width=512&height=385&srs=EPSG:26713&format=image/png instead?

Comment: still the same. Raster image is not loading up. But yes, you are right. I don't see any purpose of defining `params` that way, which I found on other online links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely that's not an obvious way of loading a WMS.

This is what have worked for me (QGIS v.2.8.1):

```
urlWithParams = "url=http://maps.itu.edu.tr:8082/geoserver/sf/wms&format=image/png&layers=sfdem&styles=&crs=EPSG:26713"
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'DEM', 'wms')
rlayer.isValid() # Returns True this time
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

We can learn a couple of things from that:

- QGIS expects a `crs` parameter instead of `srs`.
- We don't need to pass width, height, and bbox. That's something QGIS handles for us.

Comment: Thx! That worked. But is there any difference between `crs` and `srs`? I am wondering. Besides I can't load the following custom raster http://maps.itu.edu.tr:8082/geoserver/localhost/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=localhost:final&styles=&bbox=28.994875125,41.07895217,29.056140525,41.12651177&width=512&height=397&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers . May be coz it's a huge one but will look for your comment.

Comment: The new one works this way: `urlWithParams="url=http://maps.itu.edu.tr:8082/geoserver/localhost/wms&layers=final&styles=&crs=EPSG:4326&format=image/png"` Just try to leave only that set of parameters and also remove the namespace from `layers`, i.e., not `localhost:final` but only `final`. SRS was changed to CRS because the latter is more specific and tells us we are using coordinates. The former doesn't imply we use coordinates for georreferencing. See http://www.ogcnetwork.net/node/681

Comment: CRS very SRS is a WMS version issue, I think.

Comment: Thx guys. Learned quite a bit today :)