# Opening specific WMS layer in QGIS with single URL

Tags: qgis, wms

Is it possible to open a specific WMS layer in QGIS directly by entering the whole URL of this WMS?

That is, without having to open a WMS connection first and selecting the layer in the tree.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may do it with a few lines of python, see:

[How to load a WMS layer using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120823/how-to-load-a-wms-layer-using-pyqgis/121063)

[WMS layer in a QGIS 2.4 stand alone Python script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116238/wms-layer-in-a-qgis-2-4-stand-alone-python-script)

I would recommend testing in the python console in Q, if that works then you could create a simple Q plugin and include that logic for whatever layer(s) you may want to add in.

Answer (score 1):

**No**

You have to give the endpoint URL to QGIS, then QGIS appends appropriate parameters to make the map appear.