# Adding WMS layer in QGIS using Python

Tags: pyqgis, wms, qgis-2

I'm trying to write a python script to load the Environment Agency (EA) Flood Zones WMS layers into QGIS (2.14). I've provided a link to the EA's data catalogue at the bottom of this question. The layers I'm hoping to use from the catalogue are "Flood Map for Planning (Rivers and Sea) - Flood Zone 2" and "Flood Map for Planning (Rivers and Sea) - Flood Zone 3".

I have used the code below, copied from a similar question (link at the bottom), but rlayer.isValid() is always returned as False no matter how I edit the url. I can take the url in the example code below and manually add the WMS layers with no issues.

Am I missing something in my url? Or is the issue somewhere else?

Extract from my code:

```
urlWithParams = 'url=http://www.geostore.com/OGC/OGCInterface?SESSIONID=-2049535737&INTERFACE=ENVIRONMENT&version=1.3.0&service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&sld_version=1.1.0&layer=eainspire2011-wms-nat_floodzone2_inspire&format=image/png&STYLE=default'
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'EA Flood Zone 2', 'wms')
rlayer.isValid()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

[EA Spatial Data Catalogue](http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/catalogue/#/catalogue)

[Similar question - "WMS layer in a QGIS 2.4 stand alone Python script"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116238/wms-layer-in-a-qgis-2-4-stand-alone-python-script)

---

For anyone wondering the correct working links are below:

EA Flood Zone for Planning - Zone 2:
http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/wms?INTERFACE%3DENVIRONMENT--86ec354f-d465-11e4-b09e-f0def148f590

EA Flood Zone for Planning - Zone 3:
http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/wms?INTERFACE%3DENVIRONMENT--87446770-d465-11e4-b97a-f0def148f590

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is in the URL. I retrieved the "right" one from https://data.gov.uk/dataset/flood-map-for-planning-rivers-and-sea-flood-zone-2

`INTERFACE%3DENVIRONMENT--86ec354f-d465-11e4-b09e-f0def148f590` seems to act as a token for authentication to WMS service.

Try below code (tested on my machine)

`urlWithParams = 'contextuaWMSLegend=0&crs=EPSG:27700&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/png&layers=eainspire2011-wms-nat_floodzone2_inspire&styles=&url=http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/wms?INTERFACE%3DENVIRONMENT--86ec354f-d465-11e4-b09e-f0def148f590'
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'EA Flood Zone 2', 'wms')
rlayer.isValid()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)`

The result [image: Flood zone 2 EA UK]